# Printing JUnit result to file

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I want to print the results of my JUnit tests to a `.txt` file.

Following is my code:

```
try {
    //Creates html header 
    String breaks = "<html><center><p><h2>"+"Test Started on: "+df.format(date)+"</h2></p></center>";

    //Creating two files for passing and failing a test
    File pass = new File("Result_Passed-"+df.format(date)+ ".HTML");
    File failed = new File("Result_Failed-"+df.format(date)+ ".HTML");
    OutputStream fstreamF = new FileOutputStream(failed, true);
    OutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream(pass, true);
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(fstream);
    PrintStream  f= new PrintStream(fstreamF);

    //appending the html code to the two files
    p.append(breaks);
    f.append(breaks);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Following is my example testcase:

```
public void test_001_AccountWorld1() {

    // Open the MS CRM form to be tested.
    driver.get(crmServerUrl + "account");
    nameOfIFRAME = "IFRAME_CapCRM";

    PerformCRM_World1("address1_name", "address1_name", "address1_line1", "address1_postalcode", true);

    assertEquals(firstLineFromForm.toString(), "");
    assertEquals(secondLineFromForm.toString(), "Donaustadtstrasse Bürohaus 1/2 . St");
    assertEquals(postcodeFromForm.toString(), "1220");       

}
```

I've tried `p.append()` but doesn't work. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably re-inventing the wheel here.  [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), X build tool or your [CI server](http://hudson-ci.org/) should be doing this for you.

Comment: The thing is im going to have the junit project a runnable jar

Comment: double click on the junitTest.jar file and it will open and run the tests

Comment: @Limpep Why?  That's what build/CI tools do for you.

Comment: Probably should of stated im still new to java and junit testing.

Comment: @Limpep  That's cool :).  I've amended my answer so that the tools are linked.  I _strongly_ recommend that you use those tools instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.  These tools are considered industry std, so its good to learn them now.

Comment: Thanks Martijn Verburg I've managed to find a ton of information on on these tools and will be using them to help me.

Comment: @Limpep You're welcome, feel free to pop me an email if you get stuck (assuming the fine folks here at SO can't help)!

Answer (score 3):

In general , you can redirect your output to file as follows :
  - if you are using eclipse :
`Run configuration-->Commons-->OutputFile-->Your file name`
[image]

- If you run form the command line , just use :
  `java .....  >output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

When I am looking to do this, I run it command line, with a custom runner, running a custom suite. Very simple, almost no code. The suite just has the test you want to run, and the runner is below.. You can see the logic there for printing out. My code just prints out errors, but you can adapt this easily to print everything to file. Essentially you are just looking in the  result object collection of failures and successes.

```
public class UnitTestRunner {
static JUnitCore junitCore;
static Class<?> testClasses;



public static void main(String[] args) {   
    System.out.println("Running Junit Test Suite.");
     Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestSuite.class);
      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }
      System.out.println("Successful: " + result.wasSuccessful() + 
        " ran " + result.getRunCount() +" tests");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this functionality already exists. Read [this part](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_6) of JUnit's FAQ.